# Python GMail code with labels and moving emails is behaving erratically

Tags: python, gmail, imap

```
import imaplib

imap_host = 'imap.gmail.com'
imap_user = ""
imap_pass = ""
imap = ""

def SetupGMailConnection():
    global imap_user
    imap_user = 'dw*********@gmail.com'
    global imap_pass
    imap_pass = '*********'
    global imap
    imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host)
    imap.login(imap_user, imap_pass)
    imap.select('Check')

def MoveUID(inUID):
    CurrentUID = str(inUID)
    imap.uid('STORE', CurrentUID, '+X-GM-LABELS', 'Check2')

SetupGMailConnection()
MoveUID(1)
MoveUID(5)
#... UID's of multiple emails my Test group
MoveUID(16)
MoveUID(17)
imap.close()
```

The above code was run, all Emails were in both labels "Check" and "Protected" prior to running... after this was the result
[Gmail Inbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MzOc.png)

My question is why would 3 random emails be missed from the rest of the emails? I've tried moving them from Check to Check2 and Protected... despite how many times its rerun.

Comment: Where are you getting your UID list?  Are you sure they’re in your UID list?

Comment: It should be... I will double check however. The UID's actually come from copying all the messages within the inbox folder into a MS-SQL server. I then run some SQL, to check/delete old crap before moving emails into a 'Checked' area. I plan to delete these 'Checked' later on (if space is running out). The protected are emails I dont want to delete at all.

Comment: We have a winner! Well done Max... those ID's WERE the ID's, I was initially under the impression that the UID's remained the same. However I picked up from reading other comments that after an expunge command is run then the ID's could be reindexed. I havent run an expunge, but perhaps some other command has also triggered that.

Comment: MSNs can be renumbered on expunge, but not UIDs.  However, messages that are *moved* or *copied* get new UIDs in their new folders.

Comment: lots of articles that try to reinforce that you're not moving but relabeling. Either way, if I download the ID's should be the same until I 'move' them... but will need a way to track them after that.

Comment: On a generic server using `UID MOVE` or UID COPY` with `UIDPLUS` extension, the `OK` response will include a `[COPYUID]` with the UID in the destination folder.  On Google, you can instead track the `X-GM-MSGID` fetch item which is permanent for a specific message, no matter what folder it's in.